# angular route not working in chat application

Tags: angular, router

I have problems with navigation in my angular application. When I log in, the chat screen does not appear but the navbar has already logged in successfully.

This is route.ts

```
import ...

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupFormComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent},
  { path: 'chat', component: ChatroomComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

This is app.module.ts

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
],
```

And login-form.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
 ...
})
export class LoginFormComponent{
 email: string;
 password: string;
 errorMsg: string;

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

login() {
 this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
 .then(resolve => this.router.navigate(['chat']))
 .catch(error => this.errorMsg = error.message);
 }
}
```

When I login app not navigate to /chat. 
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIAbB.png)
[After login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE1IO.png)

Info version

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^4.9.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "~2.5.3"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to `/chat`you have to pass it with the `/` to the router:

```
.then(resolve => this.router.navigate(['/chat']))
```

If you do not prepend the `/` the router appends `chat` to current route.